# Python tuple fetching value

Tags: python, tuples

```
a=(1,2,3,(4,5))
```

I created a tuple. How will I fetch the value of 4 only?
It should be a single line command and without using for.
I used `a[3,0]` all possible combinations.

Comment: do you want `a[3][0]`? Think about it, `a[3]` gets you `(4, 5)` and then `[0]` on that gets you the first

Comment: it works but it's working is something like 2-D array fetching technique? but (4,5) is underlying inside this i am not understanding

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. `list`/`tuple` objects *don't have dimensions*. They are *not like* `numpy.ndarray` objects if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If location is fixed you can access element like: a[3][0]
with a[3] you will get (4,5) and a[3][0]--> 4
If location is not fixed you can iterate using a loop

```
for i in a:
    if type(i)==tuple:
        for j in i:
            print j
```

Answer (score 0):

a= (1,2,3,(4,5))
a[3][0] ==> 4

another method to just fetch 4 is

a= (1,2,3,(4,5))

ab= a[3]

now ab will be equal to (4,5)

so,

abc= ab[0]

so here abc will have 4 as output :)

Answer (score 0):

**4** is the first value in the fourth element of the tuple `a=(1,2,3,(4,5))`. In Python the index of a tuple starts at 0, so to print the first value (its index is 0) of the fourth element of the tuple `a=(1,2,3,(4,5))` type this command:

```
a[3][0]
```

Results:

```
>>> a=(1,2,3,(4,5))
>>> a[3][0]
4
>>>
```